# How to select Icon from umbraco

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I am following the Umbraco Tutorial on Our.Umbraco. I've gotten to the part where we just finished creating a master page and now we are using it to create new pages.

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Tutorials/Creating-Basic-Site/Creating-Master-Template-Part-2

I am confused by this step

> Firstly let's select an Icon - type the word "Content" into the filter and select the document icon. In description type "A simple content page". Click Save.

I honestly have no idea what this is talking about. I've followed each step successfully until this part. What filter is it talking about?

I followed the step before it just fine.

> Go to Settings > Document Types (hover) > ... > + Create > Document Type . Let's create one called "Simple Content Page".

Am I supposed to hit 'save' now or is this filter on this Docuemnt Type creation section?

Here is a photo of where I am at.

[image: Document Type Creation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment is telling you to change the icon for your Document Type.  This is the icon that will be used in the content tree for pages of this type.  To do this just click on the icon next to the name and description fields.

[image: Click on the icon]

The filter is just the search box that you can use to filter the icons.

[image: Select your icon]

Comment: I actually figured this out just before you answered it. I felt stupid and was ready to delete it. I'll save it in case anyone else runs into this. Thanks for your answer.